# Fiscal year starts in April but I want to use ISO week numbers 14 of 2018 calendar year to week 13 of 2019 calendar year

Tags: excel, week-number, fiscal

I am creating a gantt chart in excel for my plan. My formula determines the start week number and end week number, and displays "1" in a cell corresponding for each week number in a timeline. My challenge is how to use this logic when my fiscal year starts in April 2018 and ends in April 2019. If my timeline starts, say in week 46 of 2016 and ends in week 10 of 2019, my formula does not work. 
Here is the formula I am using:

```
=AND(K$7>=$H9)*(K$7<=$I9)*1
```

where K7 is my week number in a timeline, H9 = start week, I9 = end week. See the picture.

[this is a fragment of my timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhqs0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `subtract 90 days` before calculating the week number. (Assuming the start is April 1 instead of January 1.)

Or, have a named cell indicating the first day of the Fiscal Year and then use that to calculate the week number, something like:

```
([Report date] - [1st day of F'Year]) + 7 = [Week Number]
```

Comment: You might want to subtract (4/1/year()-1/1/year()+1) to auto-compensate for leap years.

Comment: Thank you, @ashleedawg and @Jeeped! I know it may sound complex, but I am trying to show ISO week numbers (thus my Fiscal Year starts on week 14 of 2018 and ends week 13 but in 2019. My gantt chart conditional formatting works with weeks in 2018 (from 13 onwards till 52) but does not understand which year weeks 1-13 are in. It also breaks when I have my start date, say week 49 2018 and end date in week 2 2019. I have added =YEAR() and trying IF AND function.